# Click on button not taking to next Activity in android

Tags: android

When i click on GO button its not taking to next Activity. I am using the following code.. can any one correct me where  am i going wrong?

```
    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // Perform action on click
             startActivity(new Intent(currentActivity.this, NextActivity.class));
         }
     });
```

Comment: what's the error you get? 'currentActivity' is that you class name?

Comment: Have you mentioned your activity in the manifest file.

Comment: yes i have mentioned activity name in manifest file

Comment: My guess? It probably is starting `NextActivity` but you have a bug in the `NextActivity` code. Without seeing the logcat it's impossible to do anything but guess.

Comment: If you solved by yourself.. Just post that as answer and accept it yourself simply.

Comment: bug in next activity so i was not getting